# css animation with setTimeout doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css

I made some animation with CSS3.

Source is so simple. Just print text and disappear it after 4s.

Below is current source.

```js
const intro1 = document.getElementsByClassName('intro1')[0];

setTimeout(() => {
  intro1.classList.remove('fade-in');
  intro1.classList.add('fade-out');
}, 3500);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 100;
}

span {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}


/* Intro animation */

.fade-in {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: fadeIn 4s;
}

.fade-out {
  animation: fadeOut 1s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <section>

      <span class="intro1 fade-in">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST </span>

    </section>
  </main>
  <script src="src.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I defined `fade-in` and `fade-out` and initialize `.intro1`'s classname to `'fade-in'`.

And delay 3.5s with `setTimeout`, remove class `fade-in` and add class `fade-out` to disappear it.

When I start it, text appear and disappear is works fine.

But after text disappear, it shows again like this.

[image]

I do not want to show again after text's opacity becomes to 0.

Any solution about this?

Thanks.

Comment: First try with the `forwards` keyword / animation-fill-mode property.

Comment: Check for `if(intro1.classList,contains("fade-out"))` then don't send it to time out again

Comment: .fade-out {
  animation: fadeOut 1s forwards;
} if this is what you're after

Comment: @VXp forwards works perfectly. Any reason here?

Comment: Let's say the animation resets when done by default, you need it in order to retain the end state at 100%.

Comment: Here is an explanation why: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

Comment: Animation will be end after 1s. Then you will see the default element in screen. If you want the element to be hidden after the animation you can set opacity 0 with transition property instead of using animation

Comment: I got it. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add this to `fade-out` class

```
.fade-out {
  animation: fadeOut 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; // that's what you need to add
}
```

**About `animation-fill-mode`:**

The `animation-fill-mode` property specifies a style for the target element when the animation is not playing (before it starts, after it ends, or both).

The animation-fill-mode property can have the following values:

`none` - Default value. Animation will not apply any styles to the element before or after it is executing

`forwards` - The element will retain the style values that is set by the last keyframe (depends on animation-direction and animation-iteration-count)

`backwards` - The element will get the style values that is set by the first keyframe (depends on animation-direction), and retain this during the animation-delay period

`both` - The animation will follow the rules for both forwards and backwards, extending the animation properties in both directions